# Unable to add objects to Arralist from different classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add different page class methods execution logs to ArraList using setter and getter methods but getting `IndexOutOfBound` exception due to different classes individual methods.

I have 4 classes

1. Base Class
2. Test Case 1 class
3. Test Case 2 class
4. Report Generation Class

I have declared ArraList<String> in Report Generation class as below

```
public ReportGeneration(){

private ArrayList<String> logger = new ArrayList<String>()

public ArrayList<String> getLogs(){
   return logger;
}


public void setLogs(String log){
   return logger.add(log);
}

public void htmlReportGeneration(){

//html report generation code
}

}
```

i'm using Report generation class method in BaseUtil class and using parent project unique methods to a add execution logs into html reports.

```
public class BaseUtil{
    
    ReportGeneration reports = new ReportGeneration();
    
    public void resultsPass(String log){
    //Pass logs code
    
    reports.setLogs(log);
    
    } 
    
    public void resultsFAIL(String log){
    
    //results fail logs code
    reports.setLogs(log);
    }
    
    public void report(){
    
    //i have folders to read one by one from results folder
    Example: 10 Test Cases results present in results folder
    
    for(int i=0;i<testcases.size();i++){'
    reports.htmlReportGeneration(report.getLogs(i).toString);
    }
    
    }
    
    }
```

I'm extending  Base class to Test Case 1 and Test Case 2 classes and using page classes methods for navigation

```
public class TestCaseOne extends Baseclass{

public void testcaseValidation(){

//using Base class results pass or fail method as per validation condition
resultsPass("Successfully Opened Browser")
resultsPass("Successfully Opened URL")
resultsFAIL("Not able to login to Account ")

page1.login(username,password)//it contains enter text , click elements etc methods in Base class and result methods included inside the unique methods
}

}
```

In this case `page1.login(username,password)` methods logs are not storing into `Arraylist<String>` only storing in case all pages methods writes in `BaseUtil class`

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to declare "logger" outside the constructor.   You can initialize it in the constructor, but declare it outside so it's scope is more global. Each TestCase is going to have it's own "reports".  When their constructor is called...  which seems OK I guess.  Just get them all at the end to generate a complete report for all cases.  Seems odd that pass/fail methods do the same thing.  You may want a bool for "passed" so you can track each one and just use one method.

Comment: pcalkins, i didn't get you ,can you please post some code for reference